# How do I adjust the leading for a single line in Microsoft Office Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I know that one can adjust the leading for an entire paragraph by going to the Paragraph dialog box in Word. However, this is a very clumsy method when I only need to adjust the leading for a single line.

How do I adjust the leading for a single line or word?

Comment: Since leading is the spacing between lines, asking how to adjust it for a single word is nonsensical (and I'm assuming you mean between a single line and the one before or after it for the other part of your question).

Comment: Well, I know that traditionally, it only makes sense to adjust it a line at a time. On the other hand, I realize that in modern word processors, the leading is affected by the word with the greatest size. Consequently, if I could get the word processor to squelch its desire to increase the size of the leading for the big word, that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way to do it.

However, you can highlight a single line AFTER you have written it and any adjustments made will affect only that line.